# Размещение AdMob c RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, admob

Столкнулся со сложностью отображения баннера вместе с `RecyclerView`.
Хочу что бы баннер отображался внизу, и скролинг элементов на него не влиял.
Вот мой код:
**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewArticle"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA:**

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs, container, false);
        AdView adView;
        adView = new AdView(getActivity());
        adView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.idAdMob));
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.footerLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest adRequest =new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice(getResources().getString(R.string.idEmulator)).build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        recyclerViewArticle = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewArticle);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerViewArticle.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), listArticle);
        recyclerViewArticle.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

Приложение запускается без ошибок но баннер не отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что **SwipeRefreshLayout** претендует на всю высоту экрана и для баннера места нема. Можно решить проблему с помощью **RelativeLayout**, указав баннеру прилепиться к низу экрана, а списку указать быть сверху баннера.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView">
        ...
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/MAIN_AD_UNIT_ID"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, круто. Получилось. Только тег `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView/>` нужно размещать ниже `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: Вместе с благодарностями можно и за ответ проголосовать) А ответ ща исправлю, хоть у меня, вроде, и так работало)

Comment: Будет репа дам голос) Пару постов еще)

Comment: А-а-а.. Нонче же мы не хэшКод) Да, забыл про репу)

Comment: Во, теперь должно быть можно)